# set boolean value on JSON object with react hooks

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Im trying to set a boolean value on an object to submit them all together, all the values comes from a form and most from text inputs, all text inputs are setting correctly except for my boolean element, Im not understanding exactly what Im doing wrong so any help is very appreciated. Heres my code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Col} from "react-bootstrap";
import EditorElement from "../components/editorElement";
import BootstrapSwitchButton from "bootstrap-switch-button-react";

export default function ListDetails({listdetails, updateData, updatingData, selectedRow}) {

    const [input, setInput, bool] = useState(
        {
            enabled: listdetails.enabled, // <-- Here I set (or want to set) the value of my boolean, the "listdetails" parameter are the default values that comes from initial fetch.
            name: listdetails.name,
            custom1: listdetails.custom1,
            id: selectedRow
        }
    );

    const updateInputs = event => setInput({...input, [event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    const updateInputsBoolean = event => setInput({...input, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked}); //<-- Here I updatethe value of my bool element
    const{enabled, name, hooktype, custom1, custom2, custom3, custom4, custom5, endpoint} = input; // <-- Here I update all the values


    const handelSubmit = evt => {
        console.log(input);
        updateData(input, bool); //<-- Here I set the collected object and set it but "bool" is not setting 
    };

    function handleBoolean(ev) { // <-- If I run this function in the boolean onChange I get the true or false value on console but I couldnt set it in the updateData (that comes from another component where I have the axios post)
        const setBool = ev.toString();
        console.log(setBool);
        //  updateData(setBool);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Col className={'col-md-6'}>

            <EditorElement name='Enable/ Disabled '>
                <div>
                <BootstrapSwitchButton
                    checked={enabled === true}
                    onstyle="primary"
                    offstyle="danger"
                    name={'enabled'}
                    value={enabled}
                    onChange={e => updateInputsBoolean(e)} // <-- Here is my boolean element that is a bootstrap switch
                />
                </div>
                {listdetails.enabled ? 'is enabled' : 'is not enabled'}
            </EditorElement>

            <EditorElement name='Name'>
                <input
                    type={'text'}
                    defaultValue={name}
                    name={'name'}
                    className={'form-control'}
                    onChange={e => updateInputs(e)}
                />
            </EditorElement>
        </Col>
        <Col className={'col-md-6'}>
            <EditorElement name='Custom1'>
                <input
                    type={'text'}
                    name={'custom1'}
                    defaultValue={custom1}
                    className={'form-control'}
                    onChange={e => updateInputs(e)}
                />
            </EditorElement>

        </Col>

        <Col style={{'marginBottom': '30px', 'marginTop': '20px'}} className={'col-md-12 text-right'}>
            <button
                style={{'marginTop': '15px', 'marginBottom': '15px'}}
                type={'button'}
                className={'btn btn-primary'}
                onClick={handelSubmit} //<-- Here I handle my submit
            >
                {updatingData ? 'Updating...' : 'Save'}
            </button>
        </Col>
    </div>
);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `useState` returns array of 2 elements, the state value/object, and a function to update state. `bool` I believe is going to just be undefined. To access `enabled ` state value you need to destructure or access it from `input`.

Comment: @DrewReese Ok! I updated my code avobe to access it from input but I get an error: ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined on this line: ------->  const updateInputsBoolean = event => setInput({...input, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked});

Comment: `BootstrapSwitchButton` onChange handler passes the checked value, not an event. https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-switch-button-react#usage

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks :) Im going to test changing to an input type checkbox instead and check if I get it that way. Cant use formik cause I can't install more dependencies to this project but I'll test passing the event in some way

Comment: @adel If you don't understand why one would use state with a form then why did you recommend a form library that uses state to manage a form? React actually recommends using [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) to manage form inputs. Controlled components ***is actually*** the react way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DrewReese helped me understand this, I was confusing BootstrapSwitchButton as a normal input and it is not like that. Here is the working code now:

```
    const [input, setInput] = useState(
    {
        enabled: listdetails.enabled,
        name: listdetails.name,
        custom1: listdetails.custom1,
        id: selectedRow
    }
    );
    const updateInputs = event => setInput({...input, [event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    const{enabled, name, custom1} = input;

    const handelSubmit = evt => {
        console.log(input);
        updateData(input);
    };

    function handleBoolean(ev) {
        const setBool = ev.toString();
        console.log(setBool);
        setInput({...input, enabled: ev}); //<-- I wasn't updating the enabled prop event here and now I make a copy of all inputs and set the event of enabled... VOILA! is working :)
    }
```

Thanks agan @DrewReese for helping me understand that